# How to find Transformation Matrix for given Column Matrix Transformation?

Tags: matrices, group-theory, transformation, symmetry

How are the transformation matrices obtained for the operations like $C_2, C_2^{'}, C_2^{''}$ in this case [image: symmetry operations on equilateral triangle], where the results of application of symmetry operations are given as: [image: result of symmetry operation] and the unitrary representations are given in the book like [image: unitrary representations]

Though I understand the unitrary representations of $I, C_3, C_3^{2}$ from the concept of [rotation of body set of axes relative to an external space set of axes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nby8Z.jpg) in 2D plane, I find it inapplicable with the given red marked results.

Further, in the case of $U(C_2^{'})$, if we apploach like $\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},-\frac{1}{2}\right) \stackrel{U(C_2^{'})}{\rightarrow}(0,1)$

$$\left[\begin{array}{c}
\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \\
-\frac{1}{2}
\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{ll}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{l}
0 \\
1
\end{array}\right]$$, then we find that $U(C_2^{'})=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
+\frac{1}{2} & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \\
\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & -\frac{1}{2}
\end{array}\right]$ is suitable for the sake of Matrix Multiplication result, rather than $\left[\begin{array}{cc}
-\frac{1}{2} & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \\
\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & +\frac{1}{2}
\end{array}\right]$ as given in this book. Though I still don't know how to obtain $U(C_2^{'})$ for given $\left[\begin{array}{c}
\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \\
-\frac{1}{2}
\end{array}\right] \&\left[\begin{array}{l}
0 \\
1
\end{array}\right]$.
Can anybody please explain this to me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think that you are right.

Comment: I suspect that the book gave the matrices for an equilateral triangle whose fisrt vertex lies on the $x$-axis, which is often done in physics/chemistry/crystallography textbooks.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos sir, can you please tell me how to obtain the transformation matrix for any  given column matrix transformation? Is there any method for doing this?

Comment: I can't help you, since I do not understand what you are asking me.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos sir, my question is that, is there any way to determine an unique matrix $U(C_2^{'})$ in this case to transform $\left[\begin{array}{c}
\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \\
-\frac{1}{2}
\end{array}\right] \rightarrow\left[\begin{array}{l}
0 \\
1
\end{array}\right]$?

Comment: That would be the matrix $A=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ such that $A.\left(\frac{\sqrt3}2,-\frac12\right)=(0,1)$ and that $A.(0,1)=\left(\frac{\sqrt3}2,-\frac12\right)$. That would be$$A=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{2} & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \\ \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & -\frac{1}2\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: Yes, but how did you obtain the matrix A here? Is there any procedure to obtain A?

Comment: The equality $A.\left(\frac{\sqrt3}2,-\frac12\right)=(0,1)$ means that $\frac{\sqrt3}2a-\frac12b=0$ and that $\frac{\sqrt3}2c-\frac12d=0$ and the equality $A.(0,1)=\left(\frac{\sqrt3}2,-\frac12\right)$ means that $b=\frac{\sqrt3}2$ and that $d=-\frac12$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142245/discussion-between-hilfsgroe-and-jose-carlos-santos).